# Adding payment model to Sold to Model in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to integrate my Hybris system with Paymetric for credit card payment for B2b implementation and store the token information got from Paymetric against the Sold to to which the user is associated.How can i add the payment model to sold Model for this implementation.

Comment: Which version of Hybris are you using? Paymetric now comes integrated in the latest version of Hybris. Please see this link:
https://www.hybris.com/ja/partner/hybris-extend/paymetric
Also you can buy the extension from Hybris.

Comment: I'm using Hybris 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Hybris doesn't come Out of the box for Paymetric it is for Cybersource. You need to get extension from Paymetric for Hybris integration and they will also provide the documentation for Integration. Paymetric will provide you extension by name **cispaymentpaymetric**. You need to place it in /bin/custom folder . 
Add the extension in \hybris\config\localextensions.xml. Then run ***ant clean all***.

**eCommerce Payment Integration for hybris® uses the XiPay® Connector for hybris (XPC4 hybris)
solution to facilitate connectivity from your hybris system to the Paymetric XiPay On-Demand Service to
perform authorization and settlement functions.**

1. The Paymetric CIS Payment Extension Module (PEM) component is
   installed and configured in the hybris local.properties file on the
   same application server (or VM) running your hybris Storefront.
2. The Paymetric CIS Payment Service Gateway (PSG) component is
   installed and configured in the paymetric-hybris.properties file on
   a separate Tomcat application server (or VM) that is running the
   hybris Payment Service.
3. The XPC4 hybris components are independent of the database and will
   work with any DB that you have implemented with your hybris
   solution.